# php file content is displayed insted of parsed

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal-7

This must be a simple errror...

I have certain php files in a Drupal site. I can execute them from inside Drupal, but when I need to execute some of them when I submit a form, I get "You don't have permission...". I added a .htaccess file in teh specific directory with this content

```
<FilesMatch "test\.php$">
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Now I am able to access the file, but the browser display the content instead of parsing it.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like php is not enabled in that directory. Enable it by `AddType`

```
<FilesMatch "test\.php$">
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
AddType text/html .php .phps
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Well... It change the behavior slightly. Now I got more or less the same content, without variable declarations in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all relplies.

It turned out that Drupal create a .htacces file in my directory with the following code after one of their security updates:

```
# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
 Options None
 Options +SymLinksifOwnerMatch
</Files>
```

That was the cause of the problem.